# How do you insert a Postgres enum value using Clojure JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc, clojure

For example, here is a product table in PostgreSQL with status as an enum:

```
create type product_status as enum ('InStock', 'OutOfStock');

create table product (
    pid            int primary key default nextval('product_pid_seq'),
    sku            text not null unique,
    name           text not null,
    description    text not null,
    quantity       int not null,
    cost           numeric(10,2) not null,
    price          numeric(10,2) not null,
    weight         numeric(10,2),
    status         product_status not null
);
```

Typical Clojure code to insert a product would be:

```
(def prod-12345 {:sku "12345"
                 :name "My Product"
                 :description "yada yada yada"
                 :quantity 100
                 :cost 42.00
                 :price 59.00
                 :weight 0.3
                 :status "InStock"})

(sql/with-connection db-spec
   (sql/insert-record :product prod-12345))
```

However, `status` is an enum so you can't insert it as a normal string without casting it to an enum:

```
'InStock'::product_status
```

I know you can do it with a prepared statement, such as:

```
INSERT INTO product (name, status) VALUES (?, ?::product_status)
```

But is there a way to do it without using a prepared statement?

Answer (score 4):

I got this working today using the `stringtype=unspecified` <strike>hack</strike> workaround.

You can add this parameter to your `db-spec` as follows:

```
(def db-spec {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
              :subprotocol "postgresql"
              :subname "//myserver:5432/mydatabase"
              :user "myuser"
              :password "mypassword"
              :stringtype "unspecified"}) ; HACK to support enums
```

Then just use `insert!` as usual.

It would be good to have a solution that doesn't weaken type safety so much.

Comment: I stumbled across [this](https://gist.github.com/rkneufeld/e5d1acbb007f47655508) as an alternative. a bit more verbose but might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Kris Jurka [replied](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/alpine.BSO.2.00.1302081124290.16163@leary.csoft.net) to the discussion Mike Sherrill cited above with a workaround:

> use the url parameter stringtype=unspecified [in the JDBC connection URL] to have setString always bind to unknown instead of varchar, which then shouldn't require any code changes.

I tried this in Java, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](https://www.bevuta.com/en/blog/using-postgresql-enums-in-clojure/) addresses the problem nicely. `jdbc` provides the [`ISQLValue` protocol](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLValue), that has only one method, `sql-value` that converts a clojure value into an sql value, represented by a [`PGObject`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html). The blog post suggest representing enums with keywords in the form `:type/value`, so `ISQLValue` can be implemented as follow:

```clj
(defn kw->pgenum [kw]
  (let [type (-> (namespace kw)
                 (s/replace "-" "_"))
        value (name kw)]
    (doto (PGobject.)
      (.setType type)
      (.setValue value))))

(extend-type clojure.lang.Keyword
  jdbc/ISQLValue
  (sql-value [kw]
    (kw->pgenum kw)))
```

In your example, you would insert your product with:

```clj
(def prod-12345 {:sku "12345"
                 :name "My Product"
                 :description "yada yada yada"
                 :quantity 100
                 :cost 42.00
                 :price 59.00
                 :weight 0.3
                 ;; magic happens here
                 :status :product_status/InStock})

(sql/with-connection db-spec
   (sql/insert-record :product prod-12345))
```

The problem is that when querying the db, the enum is a simple string instead of a keyword. This can be solved in a similar fashion by implementing the [`IResultSetReadColumn` protocol](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn):

```clj
(def +schema-enums+
  "A set of all PostgreSQL enums in schema.sql. Used to convert
  enum-values back into Clojure keywords."
  ;; add your other enums here
  #{"product_status"})

(extend-type java.lang.String
  jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn
  (result-set-read-column [val rsmeta idx]
    (let [type (.getColumnTypeName rsmeta idx)]
      (if (contains? +schema-enums+ type)
        (keyword (s/replace type "_" "-") val)
        val))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone references this question while using the successor to clojure.java.jdbc, jdbc.next, the code for inserting enums is something like:

```
(ns whatever
 (:require
  [next.jdbc.sql :as jdbc.sql]
  [next.jdbc.types :as jdbc.types]
 ))

;; ...define your database connection and data source...    

(def prod-12345 {:sku "12345"
                 :name "My Product"
                 :description "yada yada yada"
                 :quantity 100
                 :cost 42.00
                 :price 59.00
                 :weight 0.3
                 :status (jdbc.types/as-other "InStock")})

(jdbc.sql/insert! ds :product prod-12345)
```

As documented https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/doc/tips-and-tricks.md under the "Working with Enumerated Types" heading.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pass plain SQL to the back end, you'll have to use a cast. (The SQL statement `INSERT INTO product (name, status) VALUES ('SomeName', 'InStock');` should work fine.)

[Tom Lane addressed this issue](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/28690.1360299322@sss.pgh.pa.us) on pgsql-hackers a week after you asked your question.

> AFAIK this is just business as usual with JDBC: setString() implies that
>   the parameter is of a string type.  It'll fall over if the type actually
>   required is anything but a string.  (I'm no Java expert, but I seem to
>   recall that using setObject instead is the standard workaround.)
>
> Enums are not suffering any special hardship here, and I'd be against
>   weakening the type system to give them a special pass.

Our own @CraigRinger [participated in that discussion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/511B0489.8000106@2ndquadrant.com), and might have found something relevant by now.

Comment: I think @espeed is asking about the use of the Clojure library `clojure.java.jdbc`, not Java's JDBC.